# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout while using retro fit to fetch json

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am using retrofit to fetch json data from REST api. I implemented retrofit, but after launching the app it crashes with an error: `RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`. I am using a previous answer, but none of them solve my problem. Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cinsio_notif);

    initViews();


private void initViews() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.noti_recyle);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    loadJSON();
}


private void loadJSON() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://chikoop.com/api/index.php/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    notiIterface request = retrofit.create(notiIterface.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getNotification(userId, sessionId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
            adapter = new noti_adapter(data, getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

And my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/textColor">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/custome_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/cusmote_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/noti_recyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/custome_actionbar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

--------------------------------->

If anybody needed my adapter code:

```
    List<noti_sec> noti_list;
    private Context context;

    //Constructor of this class
    public noti_adapter(List<noti_sec> noti_list, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.noti_list = noti_list;
        this.context = context;
    }


    public static class notiViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CircleImageView profile_pic;
        TextView name;
        TextView about_noti;
        TextView noti_time;
        ImageView from;


        public notiViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            profile_pic = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            about_noti = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.notif_about);
            noti_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.noti_time);
            from = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_img);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public noti_adapter.notiViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.noti_msg_screen, parent, false);
        return new notiViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(notiViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.border_frame1);
        holder.name.setText(noti_list.get(position).getUsername());
        holder.about_noti.setText(noti_list.get(position).getNoti_msg());

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(image)
                .into(holder.from);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noti_list.size();
    }
```

Error log cat:

```html
02-15 20:12:16.247 13338-13338/com.release.chikoopapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
02-15 20:12:16.248 13338-13338/com.release.chikoopapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
02-15 20:12:16.406 13338-13338/com.release.chikoopapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-15 20:12:16.415 13338-13338/com.release.chikoopapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.release.chikoopapp, PID: 13338
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Empty builders!
                                                                            at com.nightonke.boommenu.ExceptionManager.judge(ExceptionManager.java:71)
                                                                            at com.nightonke.boommenu.ExceptionManager.judge(ExceptionManager.java:27)
                                                                            at com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton.doLayoutJobs(BoomMenuButton.java:346)
                                                                            at com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton.access$600(BoomMenuButton.java:55)
                                                                            at com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton$8.run(BoomMenuButton.java:1013)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Are you sure your adapter code is correct?

Comment: @Giovanni Terlingen if u need that code i will post it in edit answer.

Comment: Could you also provide the stacktrace, and not only the message?

Comment: ya sure i will provide this  in  edit answer.

Comment: @Giovanni Terlingen i add the log cat

Comment: The problem is not in your adapter, but in `BoomMenuButton.doLayoutJobs`

Comment: srry but how can i correct it?

Comment: I cannot help you without that code.

Comment: but i never implement such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not setting an adapter as soon as the RecyclerView is created can cause this problem. Since you need to download the data that is going to be displayed you may want to set an adapter with an empty dataset and set the data to it later.

A helper method like the following one can be used to avoid another error with notifying the adapter of the change in the dataset.

```
public void resetRecyclerView(final List<noti_sec> data) {
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (recyclerView.isComputingLayout()) {
            handler.post(this);
        } else {
            noti_adapter adapter = (noti_adapter)recyclerView.getAdapter();
            adapter.setData(data);// custom method in your adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: It's not a problem to have an empty recyclerview.

Comment: As Giovanni said Android generally doesn't give much trouble with setting the adapter later, this approach avoids the skipping layout error. The error causing your app to crash is in BoomMenuButton. I posted this before I saw your stacktrace.